# Replace file path in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a ridiculous time trying to simply remove a path from a pathname in Node JS. I think the problem is that `replace` is not working because the base string has slashes. But I can't seem to figure out any way to operate on the string properly. When I do replace sometimes it just removes the slashes entirely and doesn't even replace with what I asked it to.

Example.... where the heck did the slashes even go.

```
'C:\path\build\test\subfolder'.replace('b', 'z')
// "C:path\build\testsuzfolder"
```

Anyway what I'm actually trying to do is this.
Given this path I get.

`C:\path\build\test\subfolder`

Remove

`C:\path\build\test\`

But no amount of attempts with `replace` is working, even if I escape slashes.

Comment: you do realize your current code literally says replace all `b's` with `z's` which doesnt match what you are asking for in the lines afer the code?

Comment: Yes. Do you realize how inane it is to ask a function to replace two characters and end up losing random slashes along the way?

Comment: you dont understand. Is your question that you dont want the backslash removed or do you want to remove the path `C:\path\build\test\subfolder`

Comment: What is the source of the string and do you have any control over it? The "\" has special meaning and is being treated as an [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_notation). Paste it in your browser console to see what it _really_ represents. If you want an actual backslash in the string, it should be represented by "\\", assuming you have that control. Otherwise, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: It comes from Node.js `__dirname`

Answer (score 0):

Node was giving me `__dirname` with those slashes so there was no string function to do what I needed. So I had to use `split` with Node's special `path.sep` and then rejoin with the other slash type.

```
let formatted_folder = folder.split(path.sep).join('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description of what you want, you should do

```
const path = require('path');
const idx = __dirname.lastIndexOf(path.sep);
const res = __dirname.slice(idx);
```

(or `idx + 1`, if you don't need the separator itself in the result).